# Open PowerBI page without Sign-In

Tags: reactjs, powershell, selenium, nginx, powerbi

The problem. For example I have link to PowerBI report. After opening of this link, i have to `Sign-In`

```
<iframe width="2280" height="1082" src="https://app.powerbi.com/reportEmbed?reportId=fVK8cK9Wq-a046-42c1-8876-7t4HX8bZ3QYLv&groupId=ELQUhnn5u-9911-4b31-9b3-t79bHMqexVM7M&autoAuth=true&ctid=RZaQ3ybV5-4S5e-Dq6h-s5sU-CF9u2DzcHbD3x&config=ZPGx2nu47CLHbdadHpVbG5xxN4xKVCjCMK8McctjvhdmwnDkVrvRBzMqbW3F5dvckjJuuwtfV9F2AH64cad73XrZeqTH%3D" frameborder="0" allowFullScreen="true"></iframe>
```

[image]

After `Sign-In`, I can see this report.

The question. I want to make some web-server with A-record of my DNS, where i will put this URL in html page. Any client should see report without `Sign-In`. 
`Publish to Web` I can't use, because i Have only ReadOnly access to this Report. I have some scripting skills. Could You advice, maybe some React application, that will make `Sign-In` ? Or maybe varint to do this with Selenium ? I have found several variants, but in these variants, i should register application, create application_id, token_id. But i can't do this, because i am not owner of this report. I have login and password to read only of this report, and that's all.

Answer (score 1):

It's a security vulnerability to use your credentials in any webpage to display data unless you are doing it in the fashion you are displaying here, and the correct way would be to create an application regstration in AzureAD for the specific application, lock it down to the webserver, and securely authenticate to the report as the application. If the company who owns the data does not want/will not help you with this, I dont see how you will be able to accomplish your goal as it's their data. info on application registration: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/quickstart-register-app

Comment: I don't have rights to register an application. I don't have any access to do this. I have just user with PowerBI Pro license, login and password.